# An item with the same key has already been added. SSRS Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i know that there are already some forums on here, but can someone help me identify the duplicates and how to alias the column names? I believe the left joins at the bottom are creating this error in report builder.

```
SELECT  CASE A.DTASERIES
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Financial'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'Sales'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'Purchasing'
      WHEN 5 THEN 'Inventory'
      WHEN 6 THEN 'Payroll – USA'
      WHEN 7 THEN 'Project'
      ELSE ''
    END AS DTA_Series ,
    JRNENTRY AS JournalEntry,
    D.ACTNUMST AS AccountNumber,
    C.ACTDESCR AS AccountDescription,
    A.GROUPID AS DTA_GroupID,
    CODEID AS DTA_CodeID,
    GROUPAMT ,
    CASE 
    WHEN CODEAMT > 0 THEN CODEAMT
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Debit,
    CASE 
    WHEN CODEAMT < 0 THEN CODEAMT
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Credit,
    A.TRXDATE  AS TransactionDate,
    A.DTAREF AS DTA_Reference,

    DTA_GL_Reference ,
    A.DOCNUMBR AS OriginalDocumentNumber ,
    A.RMDTYPAL ,
    CASE PSTGSTUS
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Unposted'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Posted'
      ELSE ''
    END AS DTA_PostingStatus ,
    B.DOCNUMBR ,
    B.RMDTYPAL ,
    POSTDESC AS PostingDescription,
    DTAQNTY 
    FROM    dbo.DTA10100 AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DTA10200 AS B ON A.ACTINDX = B.ACTINDX
                                         AND A.DOCNUMBR = B.DOCNUMBR
                                         AND A.DTAREF = B.DTAREF
                                         AND A.DTASERIES = B.DTASERIES
                                         AND A.GROUPID = B.GROUPID
                                         AND A.SEQNUMBR = B.SEQNUMBR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00100 AS C ON A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00105 AS D ON C.ACTINDX = D.ACTINDX
```

Comment: Please try to change `LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00105 AS D ON C.ACTINDX = D.ACTINDX` into `LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00105 AS D ON A.ACTINDX = D.ACTINDX` it seems to be the same but connection should be clearer

Comment: Could you tell whether each of the columns that **doesn't** have table alias prefix (i.e. `JRNENTRY`) is for sure unique in column set of all joined tables?

Comment: In fact, I would just put a table alias on every column.  It makes it easier for future analysis & debugging.

Answer (score 2):

SSRS only looks at column names while determining fields for your dataset, and throws this error if you `SELECT` two columns with the same name from one or more tables.

In this case you have `A.RMDTYPAL` and `B.RMDTYPAL` in your `SELECT` clause, which SSRS sees as two `RMDTYPAL` columns.  Alias one or both of these and this error should go away.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14466874/1657324) for a little more information.

EDIT: (for clarity I'm only listing the two columns)

```
SELECT  
    A.RMDTYPAL AS A_RMDTYPAL,
    B.RMDTYPAL AS B_RMDTYPAL
FROM dbo.DTA10100 AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DTA10200 AS B ON A.ACTINDX = B.ACTINDX
                                     AND A.DOCNUMBR = B.DOCNUMBR
                                     AND A.DTAREF = B.DTAREF
                                     AND A.DTASERIES = B.DTASERIES
                                     AND A.GROUPID = B.GROUPID
                                     AND A.SEQNUMBR = B.SEQNUMBR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00100 AS C ON A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GL00105 AS D ON C.ACTINDX = D.ACTINDX
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply- could you give me an example of creating an alias for one of the columns. Taking A.GROUPID for example, it is aliased at the top of the statement as DTA_GroupID and when i change the A.GROUPID in the LEFT OUTER JOIN section (bottom of the query) SQL does not take it. So when i have A.DTA_GroupID = B.GROUPID the query has errors. Trying to figure out how i'm aliasing this wrong.

Comment: @JJK See edit above for an example. In SQL the [order of operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm) are `FROM` clause then `SELECT` clause, so you can't use column aliases in your join conditions.

Comment: @stubaker   if the tables contain many columns, then how to avoid listing all columns ? it's hard for maintenance in future.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps anyone else:

I had this same error in SSRS 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2. My stored procedure was doing a SELECT * FROM #Results to return the result set. There were no duplicate column names/alias's. However, when I switched it to just select all of the columns individually instead of the *, it fixed the issue.

Comment: if the tables contain many columns, then how to avoid listing all columns ? it's hard for maintenance in future.